# Down-grade Sql Server Management Studio 2014 to SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have developed project db in SSMS 2014 but where I am deploying my project, is using SSMS 2012.
Is there any way to down-grade from SSMS 2014 to SSMS 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I had the same issue which I solved by generating script of current SSMS.
You have to generate scripts of your Db created in SSMS 2014 and past it in SSMS 2012.
I hope it helps you, Helped me though.

Comment: I thought there might be another way as well but couldnt find it.

Comment: try this as alternative. I suppose you have to deploy it with in the given time so best of luck

Comment: Yeah I did the same as you are suggesting but I am curios about it there must be a way, have you found any other way when you were encountered with this type of problem?

Comment: I searched almost every where but could not find anything that would lead me to solve it with more ease rather than generating scripts.

Comment: Thanks alot anyways.